# $\mathcal{L}_2$ continuity of translation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is it true that for any real valued Borel measurable square integrable function $f$, ${\displaystyle\lim_{s\rightarrow 0}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\left(f(t-s)-f(t)\right)^2\,dt=0}$ ? If yes, then how?

Comment: That is usually done by exploiting the density of $C^{\infty}$ in $L^2$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018716/translation-operator-and-continuity

Comment: In $L^2$ that is even easier since we may switch to Fourier transforms and simply study the behaviour of $(e^{i s\xi}-1)$ close to $\xi=0$.