# For each $p\in[1,+\infty)$ , we have $\lVert k_{\varepsilon}*f\rVert_{L^{p}({\bf R}^{n}~)}\longrightarrow0$ as $\varepsilon\longrightarrow0$

Tags: lp-spaces, convolution

> Let $k_{\varepsilon}$ be a family on $\mathbb{\bf R}^{n}$ that satisfies the following properties :
>
> (i) There exists a constant $c>0$ such that $\lVert k_{\varepsilon} \rVert_{L^{1}({\bf{R}}^{n}~)}\le c$ for all $\varepsilon>0.$
>
> (ii)For each $\varepsilon>0$ , we have$$\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}k_{\varepsilon}(x)~dx=0.$$
>
> (iii) For any neighborhood $V$of the identity element $0$ of ${\bf R}^{n},$ one has $$\int_{V^{c}}|k_{\varepsilon}(x)|~dx\longrightarrow0~~as~~\varepsilon\longrightarrow0,$$
>   where $V^{c}={\bf R}^{n}-V.$
>
> If $f\in L^{p}({\bf R}^{n})$ for $p\in[1,+\infty)$ , then we have $\lVert k_{\varepsilon}*f\rVert_{L^{p}({\bf R}^{n}~)}\longrightarrow0$ as $\varepsilon\longrightarrow0$

"Here's my attempt" :**(I edited)**

Let $\delta>0$ be arbitrary given.

Firstly , we recall that
$C_{00}({\bf R}^{n})$ is dense in $L^{p}({\bf R}^{n})$
,where $C_{00}({\bf R}^{n})$ is the space of all continuous functions on ${\bf R}^{n}$ with compact support .

So, for $g\in C_{00}({\bf R}^{n})$ with compact support $L$ we have $$|g(x-y)-g(x)|^{p}\le (2\lVert g\rVert_{L^{\infty}})^{p}\chi_{LW^{-1}}$$ 
for $y$ in a relatively compact neighborhood $W$ of the identity element $0\in {\bf R}^{n}.$

Then by Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem to obtain $$\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}|g(x-y)-g(x)|^{p}~dx=0$$
Now, approximate a given $f\in L^{p}({\bf R}^{n})$ by a continuous function with compact support $g$ to deduce that 
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow0}\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}|f(x-y)-f(x)|^{p}~dx=0.$$

Choose a sufficiently small $\alpha>0$ such that 
$\lVert f(x-y)-f(x)\rVert_{L^{p}({\bf R}^{n~})}^{p}<\bigg(\frac{\delta}{2c}\bigg)^{p}~$ when $|y|\le\alpha$

Since $k_{\varepsilon}$ has integral zero for all $\varepsilon>0$ , we have 
\begin{align}
|k_{\varepsilon}*f|(x)&=\bigg|\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}k_{\varepsilon}(y)f(x-y)~dy-0~\bigg|\\
&=\bigg|\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}k_{\varepsilon}(y)f(x-y)~dy-\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}k_{\varepsilon}(y)f(x)~dy\bigg|\\
&=\bigg|\int_{{\bf R}^{n}}k_{\varepsilon}(y)\bigg(f(x-y)-f(x)\bigg)~dy\bigg|\\
&\le\bigg|\int_{|y|\le\alpha}k_{\varepsilon}(y)\bigg(f(x-y)-f(x)\bigg)~dy\bigg|~+\bigg|\int_{|y|>\alpha}k_{\varepsilon}(y)\bigg(f(x-y)-f(x)\bigg)~dy\bigg|
\end{align}

Therefore,
\begin{align}
\bigg\lVert \int_{|y|\le\alpha}k_{\varepsilon}(y)\bigg(f(x-y)-f(x)\bigg)~dy\bigg\rVert_{L^{p}({\bf R}^{n},~dx)}&\le\int_{|y|\le\alpha}|k_{\varepsilon}(y)|\lVert f(x-y)-f(x)\rVert_{L^{p}({\bf R}^{n},~dx)}~dy\\
&< \int_{|y|\le\alpha}\frac{\delta}{2c}|k_{\varepsilon}(y)|~dy\le\frac{\delta}{2}
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\bigg\lVert \int_{|y|>\alpha}k_{\varepsilon}(y)\bigg(f(x-y)-f(x)\bigg)~dy\bigg\rVert_{L^{p}({\bf R}^{n},~dx)}&\le\int_{|y|>\alpha}|k_{\varepsilon}(y)|\lVert f(x-y)-f(x)\rVert_{L^{p}({\bf R}^{n},~dx)}~dy\\
&\le \int_{|y|>\alpha}2|k_{\varepsilon}(y)|\lVert f\rVert_{L^{p}({\bf R}^{n})}~dy<\frac{\delta}{2}
\end{align}

provided we have that $\displaystyle\int_{|y|>\alpha} |k_{\varepsilon}(x)|~dy<\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{\delta}{1+\|f\|_{L^{p}({\bf R}^{n})}}~~$, for each $\varepsilon >0~~~~~-(1).$

$(1)$ actually holds since we use the nice property of the mollifier $k_{\varepsilon}$ , which is given in (iii) .

Now choose $\varepsilon_{0}>0$ such that $(1)$ is true for each $\varepsilon>0$ with $\varepsilon<\varepsilon_{0}~.$

Then for all $\delta>0$ and all $\varepsilon>0$ with $\varepsilon<\varepsilon_{0}$ , we have
$\lVert k_{\varepsilon}*f\rVert_{L^{p}({\bf R}^{n}~)}<\delta,$

so,$$\lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\lVert k_{\varepsilon}*f\rVert_{L^{p}({\bf R}^{n}~)}\le\delta.$$

Whence, our conclusion follows as $\delta\longrightarrow0.$

If you have the time , please , check my proof for validity. Any valuable suggestion or advice will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you say you're trying to prove is false - probably you left something out? (In fact if you assume in addition that $\int k_\epsilon=1$, which is not ruled out by what you do  assume, then $||f-k\epsilon*f||_p\to0$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Thanks for reminding.I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property (1) does not follow from the stated assumptions. In fact if (1) and (2) both hold, then $\|k_\varepsilon\|_{L^1}\to 0$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$ which of course implies the result, without any splitting of integrals in two parts.

The attempt to justify  (1) by saying $k_\varepsilon \in L^1$ doesn't work because for each $\varepsilon$ you have a different function $k_\epsilon$, and it will need a different $\delta_1$ for the conclusion to be true.

Generally: when we split the region of integration in two parts, it is because **different estimates** will be made on each part. By looking at the proof and seeing you do exactly the same thing for $|x|\le \alpha$ as for $|x|>\alpha$ one can tell this isn't likely to work. This is without even getting into how $|x|<\alpha$ should have been $|y|<\alpha$, etc.

---

Notice you haven't used the assumption $\int k_\varepsilon = 0$ anywhere. What it allows us to do is to subtract off a constant term from $f$ in the convolution integral:

$$
\int_{y\in\mathbb{R}^n}k_{\varepsilon}(y)f(x-y)~dy  = 
\int_{y\in \mathbb{R}^n}k_{\varepsilon}(y)(f(x-y) - f(x))~dy    
$$

What we gain is that $(f(x-y) - f(x))$ will tend to be small when $y$ is small. Of course $f$ isn't assumed continuous, but there is a kind of continuity for $L^p$ functions: 
$$
\lim_{|y|\to 0} \|f(\cdot - y) - f\|_{L^p} = 0
$$
See [Translation operator and continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018716/translation-operator-and-continuity).

Thus, by choosing sufficiently small $\alpha$ we can have $\|f(\cdot - y) - f\|_{L^p} < \gamma$, for whatever small number $\gamma$ you want, and then
$$
\left|\int_{|y|\le\alpha}k_{\varepsilon}(y)(f(x-y) - f(x))~dy    
\right| \le \gamma \int |k_\varepsilon| \le \gamma c 
 $$

The part $|y|>\alpha$ is dealt with as in your proof, using the smallness of $k_\varepsilon$.

Notice how in both cases the product is small, but for a different reason: this is typical for such proofs.

Comment: Nice proof.It is very detail and useful.