# $\forall$ partition, $\exists \delta>0$ $h<\delta\Rightarrow\exists$ a Riemann sum$<\epsilon$, can we infer $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\int_a^bf_h(x)dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The original form of the question is as follows: Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. Denote $f(x+h)$ as $f_h (x)$. If $f(x)$ is integerable on $[a-1, b+1]$, show that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx-\int_a^b f_h(x)dx\right|=0.$$ My method: $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\forall$partition of $[a,b]$ : $a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=b$, since $f(x)$ is integrable in $[a,b]$, by Lebesgue’s criterion, for each interval $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$, $\exists \eta_i\in (x_i, x_{i+1})$ such that $f$ is continuous at $\eta_i$. For each $i$, let $h_i>0$ be a real number such that $(\eta_i-h_i, \eta_i+h_i)\subset [x_i, x_{i+1}]$ and $(|x-\eta_i|<h_i)\Rightarrow (|f(x)-f(\eta_i)|<\frac{\epsilon}{b-a})$. Then $$h<\min\{h_0, h_1,..., h_{n-1}\}\Rightarrow \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|f_h(\eta_i)-f(\eta_i)|\Delta x_i<\epsilon.$$ I want to know if this can show what we want. **To promote it into a more general case,** suppose $f_h(x): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function with a parameter $h$, and it is integrable on $[a,b]$ when $0<|h|<1$. If $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\forall$ partition, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall h$ such that $0<|h|<\delta$$\exists$ a series of signal points, with their Riemann sum (The signal points can vary while $h$ varies.)with respect to the partion, the value of which is denoted as $S$, such that $|S|<\epsilon$, then can it be inferred that $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\int_a^bf_h(x)dx=0$? Prove or give counterexamples.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018716/translation-operator-and-continuity

Comment: thanks, but I don't think this answers if my promotion of the question is right

Comment: I am not sure I get your "promotion". For instance, what if $f_h = f \equiv 1$ for all $h$?

Comment: Well, but for each $h$, the Riemann sum of any partition for $[a, b]$ is $b-a>\frac{b-a}{2}$, hence it does not fit the condition of my 'promotion'. Furthermore, I would like to know where my description is ambiguous or confusing, and I will edit my question. @hal4math

Comment: I see. Well, for instance I don't follow the relationship between $\delta$, $h$ and $\varepsilon$. Specifically, how does the $\delta$ relate to the $\varepsilon$ and the partition?

Comment: You can choose arbitrary $\epsilon$ and the partition. Then a $\delta$ can be found, but different $\epsilon$ and partitions can have different $\delta$. Then $\forall h$ such that $0<h<\epsilon$, for example, for $h=\frac{\delta}{2}$ you can choose a series of signal points with respect to the partition, such that its Riemann sum is smaller than $\epsilon$. And for different $h$ the signal points can vary. (My question is indeed ambiguous here.  I will edit it.)

Comment: @Asigan: the firs part can be simplified greatly. For example assume $h>0$ for simplicity. Then
$$\begin{align}
\int^b_af(x)\,dx-\int^b_af(x+h)\,dx&=\int^b_a f(x)\,dx- \int^{b+h}_{a+h}f(x)\,dx\\
&=\int^{a+h}_af(x)\,dx -\int^{b+h}_bf(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$
Being $f$ Riemann integrable over $[a-1,b+1]$, $f$ is bounded in that interval. Say $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in[a-1,a+1]$.
Then 
$$\begin{align}
\Big|\int^{a+h}_af-\int^{b+h}_bf\Big|&\leq \int^{a+h}_a|f|+\int^{b+h}_b|f|\leq 2Mh
\end{align}$$

Comment: My intuition tells me that there should be a counterexample. Because I think your "promotion" is something similar to switching the order of the net limit of the Riemann integral and the function limit for $h\to 0$. That usually needs quite strong properties.

Answer (score 1):

My vote for the best answer goes to the ever reliable  **Oliver Diaz** who shows that you do not need any sophisticated property of the Riemann integral, nor do you need to muck around in the definition with exotic  computations involving Riemann sums. [*Moral*: never return to the actual definition of the Riemann integral except when forced at gunpoint.]

You need to observe, says Oliver, only that in the case $h>0$:

$$\begin{align} \int^b_af(x)\,dx-\int^b_af(x+h)\,dx&=\int^b_a f(x)\,dx- \int^{b+h}_{a+h}f(x)\,dx\\ &=\int^{a+h}_af(x)\,dx -\int^{b+h}_bf(x)\,dx \end{align}.$$

---

But there is always an opportunity to learn other methods.  In fact who cares about solving problems?  The only point is to acquire methods.

Here is a theorem every student of the Riemann integral should learn.

> **Theorem** (Arzelà-Osgood) If $\{f_n\}$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of Riemann integrable functions that converges pointwise to
> another Riemann integrable function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$, then
> $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx = \int_a^b f (x)\,dx.$$

Advanced students recognize that as the precursor to Lebesgue's bounded convergence theorem.

In this case take **any** sequence of real numbers $\{h_n\}$ convering to zero.  For every such sequence define $f_n(x)=f(x+h_n)$.  Observe that this sequence $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded and converges pointwise to $f$.  Apply the  Arzelà-Osgood theorem:
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b f(x+h_n)\,dx =  \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx =\int_a^b f (x)\,dx.$$

Since this is true for any such sequence it is also true for $h\to 0$.

While this is like using a sledge hammer as a nutcracker, mathematics students should get used to carrying around heavy duty equipment.  It is more fun to smash a problem to bits rather than fuss with $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s.  Also never treat the Riemann integral with undue respect: it is just a teaching tool.

**REFERENCES:**

[1] Arzelà , C. (1885). Sulla integrazione per serie. Atti Acc. Lincei Rend. 1(4): 532–537 and 596–599.

[2] Osgood, W. F. (1897). Non-uniform convergence and the integration of series term by term. Amer. J. Math. 19: 155–190.

[3] Lewin, J. W. (1986). A truly elementary approach to the bounded convergence theorem. Amer. Math. Monthly. 93(5): 395–397.

[4] Luxemburg, W. A. J. (1971). Arzelà’s dominated convergence theorem for the Riemann Integral. Amer. Math. Monthly. 78(9): 970–979.

[5] Kestelman, K. (1970). Classroom Notes: Riemann integration of limit functions. Amer. Math. Monthly. 77(2): 182–187.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am now more curious for my promotion. Could you please prove it or give a counterexample?

Comment: I don't see how your 'promotion' using Riemann sums is worth pursuing.  If you want some kind of limit like $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\int_a^bf_h(x)dx$ you can handle it by just considering sequences $h_n\to 0$ and use then standard convergence theorems.  Those are the most imporant tools and, at best, you would just be reproving them by fussing with Riemann sums.

Comment: Well, I am simply curious whether it is right...@B. S. Thomson