# What conditions are necessary for approximation of identity to converge to the function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty) \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be defined as:
\begin{align*}
\Phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{(\sqrt{4\pi t})^n}e^{-||x||^2/4t}
\end{align*}
Then denoting for a fixed $t$, $\Phi_t: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow (0,\infty) $ as $\Phi_t(x) = \Phi(x,t)$ we have the following properties:
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi_t\ dx &= 1\\
\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\Phi_t(x) &= 0, x\not=0
\end{align*}
If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n) \cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then suppose we have:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}f*\Phi_t(x) = f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align*}
(I have proved that if $f$ is continuous at $x$, then the limit holds true)
What can we say about $f$? Is it continuous $a.e$?

Comment: I think you may have it the other way around? There isn't anything special about $f$ per se other than it is well defined as you said. That's the special property of the $\Phi_t$ in the limit, as the Dirac delta is the identity for the convolution operation.

Comment: What I meant to ask is that what condition the existence of the limit impose on $f$ in some sense; if $f$ is very badly behaved it seems that the limit statement cannot hold

Answer (score 1):

A function in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is not continuous a.e in general. For example, take $n=1$ and the function $f = \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]}$ the function $f$ is nowhere continuous. Despite this fact, $\varphi_{t}*f \to f$ in $L^{1}([0,1])$ as $t \to 0.$
Here is a reminder of the proof
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left\vert \int_\mathbb{R} f(x-y)\,\varphi_{t}(y)\,dy - f(x) \right\vert \,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left\vert \int_\mathbb{R} \bigl( f(x-y)-f(x) \bigr)\,\varphi_{t}(y)\,dy \right\vert \,dx  \\
\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_\mathbb{R} \left\vert 
 \bigl( f(x-y)-f(x) \bigr)\,\varphi_{t}(y) \right\vert \,dy  \,dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \,\varphi_{t}(y) \, \int_\mathbb{R} \left\vert 
 \bigl( f(x-y)-f(x) \bigr) \right\vert \,dx  \,dy\\
=\int_{\varphi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\varphi_{1}(\frac{y}{\sqrt{t}})\, \int_\mathbb{R} \left\vert 
 \bigl( f(x-y)-f(x) \bigr) \right\vert \,dx  \,dy \\
= \int_{\varphi} \varphi_{1}(y)\, \int_\mathbb{R} \left\vert 
 \bigl( f(x-y\cdot \sqrt{t})-f(x) \bigr) \right\vert \,dx  \,dy.
$$
But the translation operator (for further clarifications look at this post [Translation operator and continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018716/translation-operator-and-continuity) ) is continuous in $L^{1}$; i.e,
$$
\lim_{a \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert f(x-a)-f(x) \vert = 0.
$$
You then apply this result with $a= y\sqrt{t}$ and you use the dominated convergence theorem.
As a dominating function you can take
$$
\varphi_{1}(y)\cdot 2\Vert f \Vert_{L^{1}}
$$
because
$$
 \varphi_{1}(y)\, \int_\mathbb{R} \left\vert 
 \bigl( f(x-y\cdot \sqrt{t})-f(x) \bigr) \right\vert \,dx \leq \varphi_{1}(y)\, \bigl( \int_\mathbb{R} \left\vert f(x-\sqrt{t}\,y) \right\vert dx + \int_\mathbb{R} \left\vert f(x) \right\vert dx \bigr) \\
= 2 \cdot \varphi_{1}(y)\cdot \Vert f \Vert_{L^{1}}
$$
Moreover, if you take a sequence of functions from $\{ \varphi_{t} \}_{t \geq 0};$ for example, $\{ \varphi_{\frac{1}{n}} \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ then you have a subsequence that converge almost everywhere to $f.$ In fact, every sequence $\{ f_{n} \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converge in $L^{1}$ to a function $f$ also admits a subsquence convergent almost everywhere to $f.$ Despite these two types of convergence we do not have that $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but then is it possible that for a 'discontinuous' everywhere function like the one you gave, $f*\Phi_t(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ pointwise? I understand that I can step down from $L^1$ convergence to pointwise almost everywhere convergence for a subsequence, but I am imposing a stronger requirement right?

Comment: Well, I have never thought of that. In general, I would say no because it is not even guaranteed the convergence almost everywhere. Even if you have a sequence like the one I gave you in the answer you may have to extract a subsequence just to have convergence almost everywhere. Thus, I would say that by selecting the right sequence you could show there is no pointwise convergence; but, to be honest, I have no idea of how to do that in this specific case. In conclusion, I could be wrong, but I would say that the statement is not true. If you find a complete answer, please let me know.